# How to change color of the Flutter showTimePicker widget

Tags: flutter

I would like to change the color of the showTimePicker. Here is my code

```
                               GestureDetector(
                                  onTap: () {
                                    Future<TimeOfDay> selectedTime =
                                        showTimePicker(
                                      initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
                                      context: context,
                                      // ignore: missing_return
                                    ).then((value) {
                                      if (value != null) {
                                       // do something
                                  },
                                  child: Image.asset(
                                    pathToCollectionPhoto,
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                  ),
                                ),
```

How can I achieve it?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to wrap your widget into a [Theme](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Theme-class.html) and provide theme data as you want.

**Example:**

```dart
Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        primaryColor: Colors.cyan, //color you want at header
        buttonTheme: ButtonTheme.of(context).copyWith(
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
            secondary: Colors
                .cyan, // Color you want for action buttons (CANCEL and OK)
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: Builder(
        builder: (context) => GestureDetector(
          onTap: () async {
            final selectedTime = await showTimePicker(
              context: context,
              initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
            );

            if (selectedTime != null) {
              // Do further task
            }
          },
          child: Image.asset(
            pathToCollectionPhoto,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: how to adjust the color of the watch hand? thank you!

Answer (score 11):

```
showTimePicker(
              context: context,
              initialTime: TimeOfDay(hour: 10, minute: 47),
              builder: (context, child) {
                return Theme(
                  data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
                    colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
                      // change the border color
                      primary: Colors.red,
                      // change the text color
                      onSurface: Colors.purple,
                    ),
                    // button colors 
                    buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
                      colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
                        primary: Colors.green,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: child,
                );
              },
            );
```

Answer (score 6):

To change the actual theme of `timePicker`, add this to the above answer inside `Theme()`:

```
timePickerTheme: TimePickerTheme.of(context).copyWith()
```

Answer (score 3):

As of right now, I got these images from the clock, (icon input and keyboard input):

clock image 1:
[image: clock image 1]

clock image 2:
[image: clock image 2]

This is the code with every variable I found that can modify the color scheme. The only thing I couldn't find is how to modify the background of AM/PM without losing the selector. (When I modify it with the TimePickerThemeData, the selector is no longer visible, so you can't see what you have selected)

```
final TimeOfDay? picked = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: _programStartingTime,
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
        return Theme(
          data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
            timePickerTheme: TimePickerThemeData(
              backgroundColor: paleBrown, // Background color
              hourMinuteTextColor: darkGreen, // Text color for hours and minutes
              dayPeriodTextColor: darkGreen, // Text color for AM/PM
              dayPeriodBorderSide: BorderSide(color: darkGreen), // Border color for AM/PM
              dialHandColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent, // Color of the hour hand
              dialTextColor: darkGreen, // Text color on the clock dial
              dialBackgroundColor: Colors.brown.shade300,
              //dayPeriodColor: lightBlue,
              //hourMinuteColor: lightBlue,
              entryModeIconColor: blueStanOut,
              helpTextStyle: const TextStyle(
                color: blueStanOut, // Set the text color for "Enter time"
              ),
              cancelButtonStyle: ButtonStyle(backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.brown.shade300), foregroundColor:MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(darkGreen)),
              confirmButtonStyle: ButtonStyle(backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.brown.shade300), foregroundColor:MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(darkGreen)),
              hourMinuteTextStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 30), // Text style for hours and minutes
            ),
            textTheme: const TextTheme(bodySmall: TextStyle(color:blueStanOut),),
            colorScheme: ColorScheme(
              primary: lightNavyBlue,
              secondary: Colors.brown.shade300,
              background: lightBlue,
              surface: lightBlue,
              onBackground: Colors.white,
              onSurface: Colors.white,
              onError: Colors.white,
              onPrimary: Colors.white,
              onSecondary: Colors.black,
              brightness: Brightness.dark,
              error: Colors.red,
            ),
            textSelectionTheme:  TextSelectionThemeData(
                  cursorColor: lighterLimeGreen,
                  selectionColor: lighterLimeGreen,
                  selectionHandleColor: lighterLimeGreen,
            ),
            cupertinoOverrideTheme: CupertinoThemeData(
              primaryColor: lighterLimeGreen,
            ),

          ),
          child: child!,
        );
      },
    );
```

The only thing I didn't manage to change is the text selection handler, as it seems bugged and hasn't been solved. ([link to issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/74890))

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether it's still be helpful for some of you. From the examples I saw, I didn't see any showing for the 24hrs. Try this it may help and I find it simple.

```
_selectTime(BuildContext context) async {
final TimeOfDay? picked = await showTimePicker(
  context: context,
  initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
    return Theme(
        data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
            colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(
              primary: Colors.green,
            )),
        child: MediaQuery(
          data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(alwaysUse24HourFormat: true),
          child: child!,
        ));
  },
);
if (picked != null) {
  setState(() {
    print('=====$picked');
    _selectedTime = "${picked.hour}:${picked.minute}";;
  });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to define it in your Material App theme that way it will hold across the App

```
MaterialApp(
   theme: _getThemeData(),
),



ThemeData _getThemeData() {
  return ThemeData(
     useMaterial3: false,
     timePickerTheme: _timePickerTheme,
   );



final _timePickerTheme = TimePickerThemeData(
  elevation: 10,
  entryModeIconColor: Colors.black,
  hourMinuteShape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
  ),
  backgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 237, 232, 243),
  dialBackgroundColor: lightColor2,
  hourMinuteTextColor: darkColor,
  dialHandColor: purple,
  hourMinuteColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) =>
      states.contains(MaterialState.selected) ? lightColor2 : lightColor),
  dayPeriodColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) =>
      states.contains(MaterialState.selected)
          ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 249, 217, 228)
          : lightColor),
  dayPeriodTextColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) =>
      states.contains(MaterialState.selected)
          ? AppColors.brandDarkBlue
          : darkColor),
  dayPeriodBorderSide: const BorderSide(
    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 125, 121, 130),
  ),
  dialTextColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) =>
      states.contains(MaterialState.selected) ? Colors.white : Colors.black),
  hourMinuteTextStyle: const TextStyle(
    fontSize: 45,
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
    color: darkColor,
  ).toPoppins(),
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
  ),
);
```